# Backreferencing repeated pattern with sed

Tags: regex, sed

Consider the following command :

```
echo "a b c d"|sed -r 's/^([^ ]* ){3}/\1/'
```

It should match `{3}` times non-space character(s) following by a space, at the beginning of the line, and replace them by itself (`\1`).

However, the result is not what I expect, `\1` returns only the last occurrence of the three matches :

```
c d
```

while I'd expect

```
a b c d
```

**The solution** is to embed the `{3}` matches in a "single pattern" :

```
echo "a b c d"|sed -r 's/^(([^ ]* ){3})/\1/'
```

However I'm curious about the reasons for which the first version doesn't work ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `([^ ]* ){3}` always returns the last match.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : That's what I'm curious about.  If not considered as a whole, I'd expect it to be considered as three patterns, so `\1` would reference the first match and `\3` the last one.  Why are the first matches dumped and not the last ?

Comment: If you post your real problem, not just example, we may be able to help solve it.  Using other program like `awk `, it may be possible to solve it en different ways, possible without any complicated regex.

Comment: @Jotne : Which real problem ?  I'm not asking for a solution, but for an explanation.  The solution itself is posted in the question.

Comment: Often people are asking for a explanation to a problem that they encounter trying to solve a problem.  Looking at the problem from an other angle may create another less complex solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first version, each time the capture group is repeated, the content of the capture group is overwritten by the new content. So it's normal that this capture group contains only the last occurrence.

Obviously, a capture group doesn't store an "history" of the content matched before *(by a previous match)*. *(except in some special regex flavors like the new regex module of python)*

Even if you repeat a capture group, the number of this group doesn't change. This number is defined by the position of the opening parenthesis in the pattern.

Comment: I accept this answer for the first pararaph, but I fail to see how the second paragraph would be "obvious".

Answer (score 2):

- `[^ ]*` Matches any character not of space zero or more times plus the following single space.
- `([^ ]* )` would capture the above matched characters. Later we could refer this group through back-referencing. like `\1`
- `([^ ]* ){3}` Repeats the pattern exactly three times. Because `[^ ]*` was only captured, it must return you the last match. To get the whole , you need to include also the repetition quantifier `{3}` inside capturing group.